# IllegalArgumentException thrown when a Path is created on a field with @Convert

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

I am trying to build a criteria query and for each incoming filter a Predicate "and"-connected, e.g.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<T> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(SampleEntity.class);
// for each filterable field create a Predicate and included in as `criteriaQuery.where(...)`
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(entityRoot));
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setMaxResults(maxResult).getSingleResult();
```

For each such filter (see commented line in code sample above) first a Path is created.

```
Path<?> path = PathBuilder.buildFromFieldName(fieldName, rootEntity);
```

This would be the method:

```
public static <T> Path<?> buildFromFieldName(String fieldName, Root<T> entity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Path<?> path = entity;
    List<String> fieldNames = Arrays.asList(fieldName.split("\\."));
    for (String fieldNamePath : fieldNames) {
        path = path.get(fieldNamePath);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Nested fields would come in e.g. named `myChild.mySet` given the following example.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_SAMPLE")
public class SampleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private SampleChildEntity myChild;
}

@Embeddable
public class SampleChildEntity {

    @Convert(converter = CommaSeparatedSetConverter.class, attributeName = "mySet")
    private Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Given that example the following exception is thrown when `criteriaBuilder.isMember(filterValue, path)` is called ("filterValue" would be the value to compare against, e.g. a search string).

Reason: In method `buildFromFieldName` first the Path is created from the root entity (SampleEntity). It then has type `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.RootImpl`. When in the for loop the fieldNamePath `myChild` is processed the Path is recreated. It then is of type `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath` and that stays like that when the last fieldNamePath `mySet` is processed. Only when the `@Convert` is removed does the type change to a `org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.PluralAttributePath` since it is a collection type.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown collection expression type 
        [org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.path.SingularAttributePath]

    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl.isMember(CriteriaBuilderImpl.java:1324)
    [... stack trace contains further local classes ...]
```

So the reason is the `@Convert` on field `mySet` in the `SampleChildEntity`. Hibernate sees the type `Set<String>` but does not use a `PluralAttributePath` but `SingularAttributePath` which causes the problem. Without the `@Convert` it works but removing the converter is not an option.

Is there any way this can work? Could the path be created differently?

Answer (score 2):

A solution/workaround would be to use a `@Formula` on a second field which refers - as a String - to the comma separated field. Then the query can be made on that String - field.

```
@Embeddable
public class SampleChildEntity {

    // no getter/setter
    @Formula(value = "MY_SET")
    private String mySetCommaSeparated;

    @Column(name = "MY_SET")
    @Convert(converter = CommaSeparatedSetConverter.class, attributeName = "mySet")
    private Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A persistent attribute that uses a converter through e.g. `@Convert` is a basic attribute and thus a `SingularAttribute` so it's absolutely correct that you see a `SingularAttributePath`. It's just wrong to assume that you can use a plural predicate on such a singular attribute. Hibernate has no way to translate this to SQL as it doesn't know what your converter does. I guess the column represents a comma separated list? In that case, you will have use e.g. a like predicate to write a filter. Something like this:

```
WHERE alias.myChild.mySet = :filterValue 
   OR alias.myChild.mySet LIKE CONCAT(:filterValue, ';%') 
   OR alias.myChild.mySet LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%;', :filterValue), ';%') 
   OR alias.myChild.mySet LIKE CONCAT('%;', :filterValue)
```

Translating this to JPA Criteria should be easy.

Comment: Yes, Hibernate works correctly. And yes, the field would contain a comma separated list. You solution should work. I posted another possibility using `@Formula`

Comment: Stumbled over the same place again and tried to use a like query, but got `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [.*,abc,.*] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]` using `cb.like(path, ".*,null,.*")`. It seems if I treat it like a String the entity manager wants to compare against a set and if a use a set query in criteria builder it can't even build the query by complaining about the SingularAttributePath.

Comment: This had been a much better approach: https://medium.com/the-soft-tradeoff/jpa-attribute-converters-are-great-dont-use-attribute-converters-8e08ea5fa797 Unfortunately, a bad design spreads over time over a large system ...